# How to get list of known Unicode characters names

Tags: perl, unicode

How can I get list of all known names, that can be used in `"\N{...}"` from perl?
Could not figure out to do with `Unicode::UCD` or other core module.

Comment: As alternative, to find a supported version of unicode in perldelta and download DerivedName.txt from https://www.unicode.org/Public/

Comment: Curiously, I just finished an article about [v5.32's enhancement to name matching](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2020/06/match-unicode-character-names-with-a-pattern/). Not that you should use it if you know the actual name.

Answer (score 8):

`Unicode::UCD` and a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Unicode::UCD qw/charinfo/;
use feature qw/say/;

say "Character names defined by Unicode ", Unicode::UCD::UnicodeVersion();
for (my $cp = 0; $cp <= 0x10FFFF; $cp += 1) {
    my $info = charinfo($cp);
    say $info->{"name"} if defined $info && $info->{"name"} ne "";
}
```

Comment: Though this won't include name aliases if that's important.

Comment: And you can make it run faster by stopping after plane 3 (0x3FFFF is the last codepoint) since pretty much everything after that is unassigned or private use. But future proofing...

Comment: And if you're interested, I have a script lying around that creates a sqlite database for the UCD for easier querying.

Comment: I [see](https://www.unicode.org/Public/14.0.0/ucd/NamesList-14.0.0d1.txt) some codes in [E0001, E0020..E007E](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE0000.pdf) (no idea what they are) and [E0100..E01EF](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE0100.pdf) (combining characters to select alternate glyphs). No idea why they're up there.

Comment: The `charnames` module does a similar job.